# Diameter of a convex hull (S) = diameter (S)

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

$\DeclareMathOperator{\diam}{diam}\DeclareMathOperator{\co}{co}\DeclareMathOperator{\Aff}{Aff}$
Let be $E$ a normed vector space (non-Banach). $S \subset E$ bounded.

Remember that $\diam(S) = \sup \{\|y-x\| : x,y \in S \} $.
Show that $\diam (co(S)) = \diam S$.

What do you think about this :

Since $S \subset \co(s)$, $\diam (\co(S)) \geq \diam S$.

Let be two convex combinations :

$$ x = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i x_i , \ \ \ \  y = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} \mu_i y_i $$

Now consider $$V = \co( \{ x_1, ..., x_n \}) \subset \Aff(\{ x_1, ..., x_n \})$$
$$W = \co( \{ y_1, ..., y_m\}) \subset \Aff(\{ y_1, ..., y_m \})$$

$V$ is convex compact in $\Aff(\{ x_1, ..., x_n \})$

$W$ is convex compact in  $\Aff(\{ y_1, ..., y_m \})$

$V - W$ is convex compact in $\Aff(\{ x_1, ..., x_n \})  - \Aff(\{ y_1, ..., y_m \})$

So it stems from $\|\cdot \|$ is convex that $\max$ is obtained on an extremal point of $V-W$.
We can easily show that an extremal point of $V-W$ is an extremal point of $V$ minus an extremal point of $W$.

Now let's consider a maximiser sequence of $\diam(\co(S))$:

$(u_n)_n, (v_n)_n$ that respects : $\| u_n - v_n\| \to_n \diam(\co(S))$.

We deduce of previously that there exists $(u^{'}_n)_n , (v^{'}_n)_n$ sequences in $S$ such as :

$$\| u_n - v_n\| \leq \| u^{'}_n - v^{'}_n\|$$

Thus : $$  \diam (\co(S)) \leq \diam S $$

Comment: don't use $x_n$ and $y_n$ for sequences after using them for other points, that's sloppy and confusing.

Comment: Ok :) Is my solution correct for you ?

Comment: No, I cannot understand your solution because it is still missing information.

Comment: Ok. Which one ?

Comment: How do you deduce that there exists $(u_n)_n$ and $(v_n)_n$?

Comment: $(u_n, v_n)_n$ always exists since it's a maximizer sequence (definition of $\sup$ ). $(u^{'}_n, v{'}_n)_n$ exists because the $\max$ is obtained on extremal points of $V$ and $W$, i.e $S$ points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106346/discussion-between-theodor-l-and-tsf).